# Empty listview displayed after doing filter operation

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a dropdown in my layout to filter my listviewes, I am used onOptionsItemSelected method to filter my listviewes,Now i am successfully filter my EventListviewes using displayEventList() method.But unfortunately the filtered listview not displayed in the layout(after filter operation an eventlistview is filtered that may not displayed in layout),Please help me to solve this problem.

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("onOptionsItemSelected", "yes");

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.all:
                displayEventInvitationList(inflater, container,savedInstanceState);
                return true;
            case R.id.event:
                displayEventList(inflater, container,savedInstanceState);
                return true;
            case R.id.invitation:
                displayInvitationList(inflater, container,savedInstanceState);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    }

    public View displayEventList(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatwindow_tab, container, false);
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<EventMO>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<EventMO> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                eventMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEventFromUser(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                }.getType());
                List<EventMO> groupEventList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (EventMO eventMO : eventMOs) {
                    groupEventList.add(eventMO);

                }
                return groupEventList;//it returns Eventlist
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<EventMO> groupEventList) {
                groupEventMoList = groupEventList;
                chatDisplayAdapter = new ChatDisplayAdapter();
                groupEventView.setAdapter(chatDisplayAdapter);
                groupEventView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
                groupEventView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                groupEventView.setOnItemClickListener(groupEventView.getOnItemClickListener());
            }

        }.execute(null, null, null);
        return view;
    }
        private class ChatDisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        public ChatDisplayAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return groupEventMoList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return groupEventMoList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int id) {
            // for sqllite management
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chatwindow, null);
                convertView.setClickable(true);
                convertView.setFocusable(true);
                chatTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_title);
                chatPlace = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_place);
                chatDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
                chatPlace.setText(groupEventMoList.get(position).getPlace());
                String actualDate = groupEventMoList.get(position).getEventDate();
                //chatDate.setText(groupEventMoList.get(position).getEventDate());
                try {
                    //date format changed here
                    Date formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(actualDate);
                    dateResult = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(formatDate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                chatDate.setText(dateResult);
                chatTitle.setText(groupEventMoList.get(position).getText());
                convertView.setTag(position);
                View v = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_window_single);
                v.getRootView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.i("position", v.getTag().toString());
                        Intent groupAct = new Intent(context, GroupChatActivity.class);
                        groupAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        groupAct.putExtra("eventMo", groupEventMoList.get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())));
                        startActivity(groupAct);
                    }

                });
            }
            return convertView;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You are setting the adapter twice, the last set is: groupEventView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);. What is dataAdapter?

Comment: i am mistaken chatdisplayadapter is only i am used..now i am edit my code..

Comment: what is the use of inflating a view here. You didn't used the inflated view?

Comment: inflate view that i am used here for display my filtered items on that..

Comment: where did u use the inflated view anywhere? you just return the view.

Comment: i am used that(view) for method that returns listviewes...now my code is running successfully after remove "dataadapter"..that place i am getting mistake..thanks for your valuable response

Answer (score 0):

**for Filtering Set Adapter with Updated List and call notifyDataSetChanged() on Adpater**

```
ChatDisplayAdapter chatDisplayAdapter =new ChatDisplayAdapter(groupEventList);
chatDisplayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**ChatDisplayAdpater.java**

```
 private class ChatDisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter<EventMO> {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        List<EventMO> groupEventMoList;
        public ChatDisplayAdapter(List<EventMO> datagroupEventMoList) {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        groupEventMoList=datagroupEventMoList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return groupEventMoList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return groupEventMoList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int id) {
            // for sqllite management
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chatwindow, null);
                convertView.setClickable(true);
                convertView.setFocusable(true);
                chatTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_title);
                chatPlace = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_place);
                chatDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
                chatPlace.setText(groupEventMoList.get(position).getPlace());
                String actualDate = groupEventMoList.get(position).getEventDate();
                //chatDate.setText(groupEventMoList.get(position).getEventDate());
                try {
                    //date format changed here
                    Date formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(actualDate);
                    dateResult = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(formatDate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                chatDate.setText(dateResult);
                chatTitle.setText(groupEventMoList.get(position).getText());
                convertView.setTag(position);
                View v = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_window_single);
                v.getRootView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.i("position", v.getTag().toString());
                        Intent groupAct = new Intent(context, GroupChatActivity.class);
                        groupAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        groupAct.putExtra("eventMo", groupEventMoList.get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())));
                        startActivity(groupAct);
                    }

                });
            }
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```